# How to get combined test coverage from functional and unit tests

Tags: selenium, ant, jenkins, functional-testing, cobertura

I have an existing Spring MVC webapp, built with Ant, set up in Jenkins for CI builds.
I am getting nice code coverage reports from my unit tests with Cobertura.

I recently added some functional/UI tests with Selenium.  Does anyone have suggestions for how I could get a single code coverage report from both functional *and* unit tests?  Has anyone done this successfully?

My end goal is to count code coverage holistically, so each class/method can be tested with the technique that makes the most sense and I hope to get close to 100% across all forms of testing.  A specific example: it might make more sense to cover controllers through end-to-end UI testing, when they don't have any real logic of their own to test in isolation.  I would then still report the code as "covered".

I am not trying to start a debate about unit tests being good/bad or TDD vs. BDD - I am asking a question about how to accomplish my goal with a given set of technologies.

I think Grails handles this nicely, but I haven't figured out how to do this with a regular webapp (Spring MVC, Java EE/JSF, etc.)

Comment: You might have better luck asking this in http://sqa.stackexchange.com/ they deal with a lot of test framework architecture questions

Comment: How can I move the question?  It wasn't an option under "close" - a few other StackExchange sites like dba and serverfault were options, though.